# discord.js-commando bot not recognizing me as the owner

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I mean, I know the ID is right, because I am using it straight from discord itself (using developers options, right clicking my name copy id).

When I use a command supposed to be for owners OR admins, it says I do not have the permissions:

```
/*jshint esversion: 6*/
const commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const bot = new commando.Client({
  commandPrefix: '%',
  owner: 'myid',
});
```

Any idea why it is pretty much ignoring this?

Comment: Hmm is this still happening? Can we see a command you're trying to use?

Comment: Yes, but I can;t remember which command, it is not too important.

Answer (score 0):

After
`owner: 'myid',` there mustn´t be a comma.
So it must be `owner: 'myid'`.

Comment: Uhm, no. That comma is totally fine. I always use a comma after ALL my last things like that. It is not needed, but it doesn't break or hinder anything either. It is just how I do things. For the record it seems the bot reconizes me as the owner, but don't have access to certain owner commands still. Not a huge deal though.

Answer (score 0):

If anything says `client.something.something` in your code, change it to `client`.
Also, you could just add another const but change

```
const bot = new commando.Client({
  commandPrefix: '%',
  owner: 'myid',
});
```

to

```
const client = new commando.Client({
  commandPrefix: '%',
  owner: 'id',
});
```

so basically just

```
const commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const bot = new commando.Client({
  commandPrefix: '%',
  owner: 'id',
});

const client = new commando.Client({
  commandPrefix: '%',
  owner: 'id',
});
```

Make sure

```
const commando = require('discord.js-commando');
```

is before the other consts.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for DiscordJS Commando say that...

```
new Commando.CommandoClient(options);
```

This is the constructor for a CommandoClient / Client Class. Try this.

Also, provide more detail as to what you are doing?

What method do you use to see if an user is the owner?

Do you use
           `ownerOnly: true`
in your command constructor?
Or do you use

```
hasPermission(msg) {
    return this.client.isOwner(msg.author);
}
```

in your command?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the bot running, and you just entered a code, you have to use <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to close the bot, then type `node .` to run the bot again. Resetting the bot always works for me.